# How to load images as per the respective image names after splitting the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an issue trying to get my images to store in the respective lists. I have 8000+ images which I then split into train, test and validation sets. I do this by using the `split-folders` library.

`splitfolders.ratio(split_data_path, output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, .1, .1), group_prefix=None, move=False)`

This code does the job fine, creates an output folder with the respective sub-folders. However, what I want to do is store the respective images of train, test and val as per the image names which are stored in a CSV file.

The code below is how I have stored all the filenames into a list from the CSV file, this results in 8327 records. The picture is just a sample of the filenames of the whole dataset.

[image: Filenames]

```
filenames = []
for i in range(len(labels)):
    filenames.append(labels.iloc[i]['filename'])
len(filenames)
```

Now when I try to store the images as per the filenames for my validation dataset split, I get the same number of instances which is 8327. The same thing happens for my train and test split.

```
val_data = []
for i in range(len(filenames)):
    imagePath2 = os.path.sep.join([r'C:\Users\conm\Desktop\Stenosis-Project\output\val\stenosis', f'{filenames[i]}'])
    image2 = cv2.imread(imagePath2)
    val_data.append(image2)
```

Is it possible to match the file names from the validation images split and with the filenames from the CSV file then store it in a list or numpy array which I can then use with my bounding box labels?

Comment: this is a **pandas** question. you forgot to tag `pandas`. I've also removed the OpenCV tag because you appear to have no issue with the image reading itself.